# multiple where clause failed - assigning same string for different column values

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

In my code there is a function to retrieve rows in which countdesc= inputText and countdate= datevalue. But both countdesc and countdate are getting assigned as EditText .the logcat is given here.please help me find the error.

```
public Cursor fetchEventByName(String inputText,String datevalue ) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length () == 0) {
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_EVENT },
        null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {

             mCursor= db.rawQuery("select * from <countable> where  countdesc='" + inputText + "' and countdate='" + datevalue+ "'", null);
        }

        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }
```

logcat

```
08-16 06:28:11.730: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.events1/example.events1.Getclicker}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "<": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from <countable> where  countdesc='Yalahanka' and countdate='Yalahanka'
```

Comment: From what I see in the logcat, you just need to remove < and > surrounding the table name. your query should look like "select * from countable where  countdesc='....

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String table="myTbl";
    String whereClause = "Number = ? AND Name = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { strNum };
 whereArgs[1] = new String[] { strNname };
    db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();
```

In the above code, i'm deleting entries with multiple where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line in if else loop with this

```
 mCursor= db.rawQuery("select * from countable where  countdesc='" + inputText + "' and countdate='" + datevalue+ "'", null);
```

Comment: can u post your whole log cat? @user2681154